# Letodms (Document Management System) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, php7

I'm migrating my system from 14.04. to 18.04. and was happy to see that there was a letodms package in the repository that was smoothly integrated by apt adding all necessities like the apache, php7, mysql package etc.

However, configuring letodms was not as easy as I remembered it from 2 years ago, and there seems to be little to no documentation on the net nowadays.

When pointing a browser to http://localhost/letodms (/var/www/html/letodms) there is no installation routine in php as there used to be, simply an empty page is displayed.

The apache reports an error in it's logs, saying that mysql_connect is an undefined function.

Evidently mysql_connect is depreciated since php5 and I have tried several workarounds I found on the net, but none worked.

I expected, since the package is in the repository, that someone had it working, and am wondering if I "forgot to put gas i the tank" in the sense of not seeing a mistake I am making that is so basic that I don't think of it.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: you check http://localhost/phpmyadmin/  is working?

Comment: How did you installed letodms? It is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=letodms)...

Comment: Yes. It's working fine.

Comment: I installed it per apt  [sudo apt install letodms] and it went in smoothly.

Comment: This error appears  in the apache's error.log repetitively:    Part 1      [php7:error] [pid 30885] [client 127.0.0.1:36640] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /usr/share/php/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php:461\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/adodb/

Comment: Part 2     adodb.inc.php(670): ADODB_mysql->_connect('localhost', 'letodms', '\\xC2\\xXXXXXX', 'letodms')\n#1 /usr/share/php/LetoDMS/Core/inc.DBAccess.php(99): ADOConnection->Connect('localhost', 'letodms', '\\xC2\\xXXXXXX', 'letodms')\n#2 /usr/share/letodms/inc/inc.DBInit.php(27): LetoDMS_Core_DatabaseAccess->connect()\n#3 /usr/share/letodms/out/out.ViewFolder.php(23): include('/usr/share/leto...')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 461

Comment: Looks like the cause is that adodb is not using the msqli-driver thus colliding with php >5.5 as others have encountered the same problem:  https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/issues/308

Comment: SOLVED. Letodms code calls adodb's (obsolete) mysql -driver instead of the mysqli-driver. In /etc/letodms/settings.xml. I changed  dbDriver = "mysql" to dbDriver = "mysqli" (in line 155 <database> (...) </database> and everything works fine.